# Blender 2.93 render problem with Cycles: "Out of memory in cuLaunchKernel" what does this mean?

Tags: rendering

[image]

Hey guys I'm still really new to blender, and I have a creature sculpt with quite complex shader nodes and some hair particles. When I try to render with Cycles on my GPU, I get this error "Out of memory in cuLaunchKernel." What does this mean?

My specs are
Nvidia Geforce RTX 3060 laptop GPU
intel i7-10870H CPU @ 2.20ghz
32gb RAM

Comment: Your graphic card is out of memory. Do you use large texture files and do your models have many subdivisions?

Comment: yes to both :( but i have a powerful rig setup tho idk

Comment: do u think this might also be bcos the intel gpu is set as my primary gpu instead of my nvidia gpu in the windows settings? I've now changed that in my nvidia control panel to use my nvidia as the default so hopefully that helps. Does blender know to distinguish between the 2 gpus when i select the option in CUda or Optix?

Comment: My laptop has an internal GPU and external 3070 and Blender uses the right one for me. You can check in Edit>Preferences>System>Cycles Render devies to see if your GPU is checked or not.

Comment: If that is OK, you can try this to see if it works: In Render Settings>Enable Simplify and set your Max Subdivision to 0 and Texture Limit to 1024 and Child particles to around 0.500. If your Scene renders after this, it probably means your Scene is too big. Try it out and see what it does. I've faced that issue before and this kinda helped me as well.

Comment: yo thank u!! will try this out when im home later! yesterday i tried downloading other blend files that i had in my blender tutorials and those relatively high poly stuff managed to render so im thinking it might j be that i made this scene too complicated or someting